# Keep getting SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in Firebug

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and just started learning JavaScript. When trying to create an object print out some things Firebug keeps giving me the error code

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

What does this mean? I don't see a problem in my code.

```
var player1 = {
    name: "fred",
    score: 1000,
    rank: 1
};
var player2 = {
    name: "Sam",
    score: 10000000,
    rank: 5
};

function playerDetails() {
    console.log(this.name + "has a rank of" this.rank + "and a score of" + this.score);
};
player1.logDetails = playerDetails();
player2.logDetails = playerDetails();
player1.logDetails();
```

Comment: you missed `+` between `"has a rank of" this.rank` this should be `"has a rank of"+this.rank`

Comment: Thanks. But now it says typeError: player1.logDetails is not a function. This is how the instructor wrote it though and it worked fine for him. Is it firebug?

Comment: what you want to do is assign the function `playerDetails` to the property `player1.logDetails`. What you are actually doing is assigning the result of the function-call `playerDetails()` to the property. Your code should read `player1.logDetails = playerDetails;` instead.

Answer (score 3):

For the start. Try something easier.

```
var player1 = { name:"fred", score: 1000, rank: 1 };
var player2 = { name: "Sam", score:10000000, rank: 5 };

function playerDetails (player) {

console.log(player.name + "has a rank of" + player.rank + "and a score of" + player.score);

};

playerDetails(player1);
playerDetails(player2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Though all fire bug prints out when I put this code in is undefined.